# How can I combine internet from two sources on my macbook and get increased speed?

Tags: network, wifi, tethering, internet-sharing

I have two sources of internet,

[image]

I want to combine both the internet sources and get increased speed.
I have noticed by testing, I can either use Ethernet internet or the Wifi Internet at one time, but by default both don't combine.

Comment: Do they actually connect to the outside world by different methods, or do they go eventually through the same router/internet account? If the latter, there will be absolutely no gain, your internal connection will almost certainly be far faster than your external.

Comment: of-course yes, wifi is connected to my phone hotspot and ethernet is connected to router .

Answer (score 6):

What you're referring to is called Internet Bonding.

You can't simply turn on two different Internet connections and have everything work - you need an intermediary whether it be a dedicated router or 3rd party software to properly manage the packets as they split between the two connections and then have them reassemble back on the other end.

It's very similar to [Link Aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation) but instead of being internal where your host (computer) and switch must support it, you must have an ISP or a 3rd party service that will do this for you.

Here's a few companies that do Internet bonding:

- [Speedify](https://speedify.com/blog/enterprise-internet-bonding-software/what-is-broadband-bonding/)
- [XRoads Networks](http://www.xroadsnetworks.com/internet_bonding/internet_bonding.html)
- [ZifiLink](https://www.zifilink.com/) (3G, 4G, LTE bonding)

Normally, this is done at the Enterprise level where a router can have multiple WAN connections (I did this with 3Com/HP and Cisco gear) or in remote location where broadband was more expensive than multiple cellular data networks.

As for software, there's

- [OpenMCTC Router](https://www.openmptcprouter.com/)
- [pfSense Multiple WAN connections](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/book/multiwan/index.html)

In these instances, *you're* acting as the bonding service provider.  Given that it's available on pfSense which is the same firewall that macOS uses (`pf`) it's conceivable that you can bond multiple Internet connections using the built in firewall.

Comment: so is there a third party software available ?

Comment: I tried connecting usb to draytek router but it didn't worked.

Comment: I’m not familiar with that router, can you post a link?

Comment: https://www.draytek.co.uk/products/business/vigor-2860

Comment: Those USB ports is not for your computer/phone.  It's for storage (NAS features), a printer (print server), the modem or cellular dongle.  It's not for your phone or laptop.  When you connect your phone via USB, you're tethering, but it's not a modem.  Likewise, if you use an LTE USB adapter, it's not tethering either, it's an actual network interface.  There's a big difference.  See this image:  https://www.draytek.co.uk/images/v2860-front-panel1.jpg